# Opera makes ajax requests twice when the page is loaded the first time

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, opera

I'm facing a little problem in opera. I couldn't replicate this in other browsers.

I have a page that is loading. Once the page is loaded, using JavaScript I make an ajax request to load some information in json format(I'm using jQuery).
The problem is that opera makes the ajax request twice. In opera dragonfly it shows me that it has only made 1 request, but my http server says different.

The requested page is something like this: `http://localhost/session&_=1352301441410` where the last number is random.

I also added the following response headers:

```
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 07 Nov 2012 15:17:22 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

I think the problem is something related with cache, since this occurs only when the page is loaded the first time, or when I clear the cache.
I'm using the latest opera: Opera 12.10

On other browsers everything is working OK.

Comment: Where is your javascript? it could be a race condition that intermittently causes it to happen twice.

Comment: my script is on a separate js file in header tag.  First I thought the same. That is a bug from me. But dragonfly shows me that only one request has been made. When I tested in firefox, firebug also showed me only 1 request.  But only opera makes 2 requests when the the cache is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem some time ago with Chrome. It called the same function twice (but it showed only once in the timeline of the debugger. To resolve it, i used a variable that is set to 1 as soon as the function is called, and set to 0 when it is completed. of course, the function will not be called if the variable is 1. The snippet of code that calls the function is this:

```
if (security_var == 0)
{
  security_var = 1;
  function_whatever();
}
else
{
  alert('Function called while variable is 1');
}
```

while the function will be something like this:

```
function function_whatever()
{
  //the code bla bla bla
  //.....

  security_var = 0;
}
```

Just remember that, if your function has other ways to exit, you should put the `security_var = 0;` there, too :) It's not the best way to avoid problems (should, for example, your function end for whatever reason, you could find yourself unable to start it again, because the variable is set to 1), but it's ok for test purposes; the alert lets you verify it.